# Traveling road bikes that disassemble

Tags: travelling

I did a ride with a guy who had a bike like this http://www.sandsmachine.com/a_rod_r2.htm

It was a regular road bike (Allow) that you could disassemble and fit in a case slightly larger than the wheels.

He said he used his bike for Triathlons and other riding events.

I am interested in configuring my own bike to work this way (Regular road bike, steel)

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is a good fit for the Q&A format. It's basically a shopping question and I think the answer would be readily available on google.

Comment: @arne surprisingly the question is not that easy to answer on Google - Unless you can give me the query?

Comment: Just because it is not amenable to a google search does make it an a good fit for a Q&A format.

Comment: @Blam Sorry, I guess I could re-phrase the question? Something like I am interested in a bike that can disassemble. What bike/methods have other recommended. I just figured the question I posed was a better fit. I had no idea of S&S coupling before the the post and now I know.

Comment: I have also learned about Ritchey BreakAway frames now too!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mechanism that allows disassembling the frame is called an [S&S Coupling, Bicycle Torque Coupling or BTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_Torque_Coupling).  Searching for bikes with this mechanism should allow you find other models of bikes that can be disassembled in the same manner.

Comment: Yep, several bikes are sold with S&S couplers, or you can get a frame shop to install them on an existing bike (if the bike is the right configuration).  Probably must be a steel frame, with round tubes, and not too far removed from the standard "diamond" configuration.

Comment: The wikipedia page says that S&S couplers are available in stainless steel, chromoly steel, and titanium. So a frame made out of any of those materials should be compatible, provided you can find a source for the couplers, and a person with the necessary skills to adapt the frame to them.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy a new frame or order a custom frame with S&S couplers. Some builders will also add them after market to some frames; usually steel or titanium. S&S couplers add around 1 pound to the weight of a single frame. Another lighter, cheaper option is Ritchey Break-away frames. They're available in steel or titanium, road or cross configurations. Some people have suggested the Break-away may not be as stiff as S&S, but it's easy to find happy owners of both on forums. I only have first hand experience with S&S couplers on a steel tandem. They were problem-free in that application.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you will use your bike there are a few alternatives for travelling.

For touring: It might be worth while considering bikes that come with a coupler installed already such as the Surly Trucker Deluxe (http://surlybikes.com/bikes/trucker_deluxe). I've seen the frame online for around $1000. Ritchey also makes a similar frame.

For commuting: With a more commuter minded focus Montague makes bikes that fold in half though they're going to be larger than your wheels even while folded.

For racing: Buy a bike specific travel bag such as the EVOC bag. If you really want to race hard you'll want a race specific bike not one with extra mechanisms made for traveling.